# prevent this unsafe cross threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have this code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*start update timer*/
            System.Timers.Timer updateticker = new System.Timers.Timer();
            updateticker.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(update_overload);
            //10 minute ticker
            updateticker.Interval = 600000;
            //30 sec ticker
            updateticker.Interval = 30000;
            updateticker.Enabled = true;

            System.Timers.Timer guiTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            guiTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(idle_display);
            //1 minute ticker
            guiTimer.Interval = 60000;
            //30 sec ticker
            //updateticker.Interval = 30000;
            guiTimer.Enabled = true;

        }

 //run front end idle timer
        public void idle_display(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (minutes_left > 0) {
                minutes_left = minutes_left - 1;
            }

            lbl_dyn_status.Text = "Time until next automatic update: "+ minutes_left + " minutes.";
        }
```

Visual studio is flagging the final line of the second function as unsafe cross threading. Can anyone suggest how I rewrite this to solve the issue?

Cheers

Comment: As stated in my answer, counting time, iteratively like this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

Use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer`

or use [SynchronizingObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) property of Timer.

> When SynchronizingObject is null, the method that handles the Elapsed event is called on a thread from the system-thread pool. For more information on system-thread pools, see ThreadPool.
>
> When the Elapsed event is handled by a visual Windows Forms component, such as a button, accessing the component through the system-thread pool might result in an exception or just might not work. Avoid this effect by setting SynchronizingObject to a Windows Forms component, which causes the method that handles the Elapsed event to be called on the same thread that the component was created on.

Answer (score 2):

As others suggested, use [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx). Unlike [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), which operates on Thread Pool threads, it guarantees you that the tick event is invoked on the UI thread.

The UI thread is the only thread allows to modify the UI. This is why you get an exception trying to write `lbl_dyn_status.Text`.

Comment: What is the purpose of system.timers.timer if it cannot interact with the user?

Comment: It is useful for anything that has no user interaction, for instance a periodically running action in a windows service.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer instead of System.Timers.Timer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the handler to

```
public void IdleDisplay(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (lbl_dyn_status.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(IdleDisplay)
    }
    else
    {
        if (minutes_left > 0)
        {
            minutes_left = minutes_left - 1;
        }

        lbl_dyn_status.Text = string.Format(
            "Time until next automatic update: {0} minutes.",
             minutes_left);
    }
}
```

This way allows you to use the thread free `System.Threading.Timer` but checks for a cross-thread call in the handler. If detected the call is invoked on the main GUI thread, via the `Form` class.

This is described [on MSDN in more detail here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx)

More generally, you should not use timers to count time like this. The more thread bound your timer is, the more it is likely to diverge from real elapsed time. You can use your timer to schedule an update of your clock but, you should calculate elapsed time since some fixed point rather than using an iterative counter.